# Joining two time series and replacing with NA if there is a numeric value in the second dataframe

Tags: r, join, merge, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two different time series dataframes and I just would like to join them with a condition of replacing with na if there is a numeric value in the second time series dataframe. Here you can find the related the dataframes.

```
library(lubridate)

first_df = data.frame(date = seq(ymd_hm("2019.12.01 00:00"),ymd_hm("2019.12.01 05:00"),by=3600), t1=c(1:6),t2=(7:12),t3=c(13:18),t4=c(19:24),stringsAsFactors = F)

first_df[-1]=apply(first_df[-1], c(1,2), as.numeric)

print(first_df)

                 date t1 t2 t3 t4
1 2019-12-01 00:00:00  1  7 13 19
2 2019-12-01 01:00:00  2  8 14 20
3 2019-12-01 02:00:00  3  9 15 21
4 2019-12-01 03:00:00  4 10 16 22
5 2019-12-01 04:00:00  5 11 17 23
6 2019-12-01 05:00:00  6 12 18 24

second_df = data.frame(date = seq(ymd_hm("2019.12.01 01:00"),ymd_hm("2019.12.01 04:00"),by=3600), t2=c(31,"NaN","NaN",34),t3=c(37:40),stringsAsFactors = F)

second_df[-1]=apply(second_df[-1], c(1,2), as.numeric)

print(second_df)

                 date  t2 t3
1 2019-12-01 01:00:00  31 37
2 2019-12-01 02:00:00 NaN 38
3 2019-12-01 03:00:00 NaN 39
4 2019-12-01 04:00:00  34 40
```

So, the desired output can also be found below.

```
                 date t1 t2 t3 t4
1 2019-12-01 00:00:00  1  7 13 19
2 2019-12-01 01:00:00  2 NA NA 20
3 2019-12-01 02:00:00  3  9 NA 21
4 2019-12-01 03:00:00  4 10 NA 22
5 2019-12-01 04:00:00  5 NA NA 23
6 2019-12-01 05:00:00  6 12 18 24
```

I just would like to proceed with dplyr, however any answer will be appreciated. Btw, "NaN" values inside the second_df came from xts package while taking the hourly averages.

Note: Full joining these two data frames by date and after joining, taking the related TRUE indices of numeric values of second_df is an option. Then by using these indices, related values can be replaced with NA in first_df. However, I also think that it's not the best solution for my problem?

Note 2: I have just added "stringAsFactors = F" and make all the values numeric in dataframes with the warning of StupidWolf. It is the same structure now for both dataframes that I am struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data, you can set the NaN without quotes.

```
library(lubridate)

first_df = data.frame(
date = seq(ymd_hm("2019.12.01 00:00"),ymd_hm("2019.12.01 05:00"),by=3600), 
t1=c(1:6),t2=(7:12),t3=c(13:18)
,t4=c(19:24),stringsAsFactors = F)

second_df = data.frame(
date = seq(ymd_hm("2019.12.01 01:00"),ymd_hm("2019.12.01 04:00"),by=3600), 
t2=c(31,NaN,NaN,34),t3=c(37:40),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

If you do:

```
tochange = !is.na(second_df[,c("t2","t3")]) 
tochange

        t2   t3
[1,]  TRUE TRUE
[2,] FALSE TRUE
[3,] FALSE TRUE
[4,]  TRUE TRUE
```

You can see a boolean on the values you need to replace, in the second data.frame. So it's a matter of finding the four rows in your first data frame that matches the date values:

```
# get the rows
rowIdx = match(second_df$date,first_df$date)
# specify rows, columns then the boolean
first_df[rowIdx,c("t2","t3")][tochange] = NA
first_df

                 date t1 t2 t3 t4
1 2019-12-01 00:00:00  1  7 13 19
2 2019-12-01 01:00:00  2 NA NA 20
3 2019-12-01 02:00:00  3  9 NA 21
4 2019-12-01 03:00:00  4 10 NA 22
5 2019-12-01 04:00:00  5 NA NA 23
6 2019-12-01 05:00:00  6 12 18 24
```

The above works if your missing value is proper NA values in R. See https://www.statmethods.net/input/missingdata.html, and I think it's good practice to make sure your variables use this.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience with dataframes. I have just edited the code in order to create a dataframe just like I am struggling in R.

Comment: @Cyric, thanks for updating your data. I have edited my answer. It works with your dataframe now

Comment: Thank you @StupidWolf. I have tried to use is.numeric instead of !is.na. It was useless even though I tried it with apply function. Now it's okay.